# how to deal with Computed and Destructuring assignment in Vue3？

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

```js
const index = ref('child1')

const children = {
    child1:{ name:'foo' },
  child2:{ name:'bar' },
}

// case 1. I want to destructur and get name variable when index variable is changed to 'child2'. Because computed is not used here, it is not responsive, name variable still is 'foo'
const {name} = children[index.value]

// case 2. After using computed
const child = computed(() => children[index.value])

// Because I used Computed, I got the child object, but I can't deconstruct it
// so I need to use child.name in the template, and i dont want that.
// My puzzle is how to use the name field directly, as in case 1, and responsive as in case 2
// maybe Reactive with toRefs？
```

I got a [playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to explain my confusion

I expect to use the name field directly, as in case 1, and responsive as in case 2

Comment: Are you `script setup`? Are you fine with Experimental Features?

Comment: @Dimava script setup isn't experimental, it is the recommended way for Vue 3 composition API

Comment: @Thomas Reactivity Transform is experimental, that's why I'm asking

Comment: @Dimava yeah，I am `script setup`,but the experimental function is not considered temporarily

Comment: I don't think it is possible to destructure a ref in Vue 3.4+

Answer (score 2):

a) deconstruct with `toRef` or `toRefs`:

```
const child = computed(() => children[index.value])
const { name } = toRefs(child)
const name1 = toRef(child, 'name')
```

b) get name directly

```
const childName = computed(() => children[index.value].name)
```

<s>c) use Reactivity Transform (experimental)</s> **removed in the vue 3.4**

```
const child = computed(() => children[index.value])
const { name } = $( child ) // name is string
```

Comment: a)  I can't get `name` and `name1`, is that useful?

Comment: `toRefs` does not work, see [this playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Answer (score 0):

You could define the computed to be the name directly:

```
const name = computed(() => children[index.value].name);
```

Comment: I could, but if a `child` object has many keys, more variables need to be defined

Comment: and that is why i ask this question

Comment: Then @Dimava's answer is the way to go.